# Trying to store StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, u128, (SomeStruct1, SomeStruct2<SomeType>), ValueQuery>

Tags: storagemap

Getting the error:

the trait `MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `SomeStruct`

If I add MaxEncodedLen to the #[derive()] list it changes to this:

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `max_encoded_len` found for struct `frame_support::dispatch::Vec<u8>` in the current scope
--> /home/aely/substrate-node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs:42:9

How do I store a struct that has a Vec or is a string in js?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store String in Subtrate by using Vec<u8>:](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/store-string-in-subtrate-by-using-vecu8)

Comment: Im running into more problems trying to use BoundedVec. The second awswer is talking about smart contracts. Is there a working example I can look at anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working.

[How to store a string in substrate storage?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6197/how-to-store-a-string-in-substrate-storage)

Instead of using

```
Struct {
    string_field: Vec<u8>
}
```

Using:

```
Struct {
   string_field: [u8; some_limit]
}
```

I also had to import MaxEncodedLength and add it to the #[derive()] list as well.

Answer (score 0):

use can use `BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<128>>` instead using the `Vec<8>` in the struct .
if you need to use struct into the storage you have to use this macro with the storage :

`#[pallet::unbounded]`

**Exmaple :**

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::unbounded]
#[pallet::getter(fn storage)]
pub(super) type storage<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<
    _,
    Twox64Concat,
    HashId<T>,
    Twox64Concat,
    AccountOf<T>,
    /*struct*/,
    OptionQuery,
>;
```

The BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<128>> type signifies a vector of u8 elements with a bounded length, in this case, a maximum length of 128 elements. This construct is typical in Substrate-based blockchains to put an upper limit on the size of dynamic collections to ensure that they do not grow indefinitely, which could lead to performance issues or exploits.